# In Azure how can a Startup Task communicate with the Role that contains it?

Tags: azure

I have a startup task in a Windows Azure Working Role. This startup task makes changes to the registry that require a reboot in the VM. So I need a way to signal the Role that it needs to reboot.

So far my solution is for the Startup Task to create a dummy file if it finds that the registry has already been modified (which means that the Role already rebooted). So the first time the role runs it doesn't find the dummy file so it throws an unhandled exception which causes the role to be rebooted.

Next time the startup task kicks off again and it creates the dummy file so that we don't end up in an endless loop.

This sounds like a very hacky solution. Is there a more elegant way of doing this? I thought an easy way would be to force a reboot from the Startup task but couldn't find how to do that either.

Comment: For anyone else who stumbles on this question: there is nothing hacky or unclean about writing and checking for the existence of a file.  This method is at least endorsed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj129544.aspx) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290696(v=sql.110).aspx).  In my opinion it is *more* maintainable and clean to just check for a file.  If you are checking specific registry key, now you have *two* places to change the code (the writing code and checking code) if the registry key location ever changes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this seems reasonable.  However, if you are changing the registry, why not just check the registry to see if you already changed it?  Just put your installer in a script (e.g. yourinstaller.cmd), but call another script first to check before launching (e.g. startup.cmd).  The 'youinstaller.cmd' would always reboot.  Make sense?

```
@echo off
setlocal
set regpath=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Foo\Bar
set regvalue=SomeKeyYouSet
set regdata=SomeValueYouSet
reg query "%regpath%" /v "%regvalue%" | find /i "%regdata%"
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Data Not Found!
    call yourinstaller.cmd
    EXIT /B /0
)
```

Comment: thanks! I think this is definitely cleaner than my current solution and doesn't have the problem of having a file as a flag (which is flaky as commented by David).

Answer (score 3):

According to [this blog post](http://www.robblackwell.org.uk/2010/12/02/java-jdbc-to-sqlazure-connection-drop-workaround.html) which seems to do something very similar to what you're trying to do, you're not too far off.  It uses a similar temp file trick, but does it all in the batch file, as well as the restarting.  To get the restarting to work they use the [shutdown command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003%28TechNet.10%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I can't imagine how the temp file technique will work. Every single time the instance is rebooted, you'll need to install the registry values. You can't depend on registry values persisting after a role recycle, and you can't conditionally run a startup task.

Can you elaborate a bit as to *why* you need to reboot after updating the registry? If you do, indeed, have a scenario that has to have those registry values set prior to booting, then you should be looking into a VM Role. But curiosity is killing this cat.

Comment: David, why do you think I cannot depend on the registry value persisting? It's working for me and I remember from watching a channel9 video that rebooting a Role was something possible. Changes to some registry Hives only take place after rebooting a machine (well not the changes, but the effect on the system).

Comment: What happens if your instance is updated with a new OS, or brought back up on another server? It's a fresh restart. Registry changes are not part of your role's definition, unless you build a VM Role. So if you look for your temp file and it's there, you could be falsely assuming you have the reg values set.

Comment: If the OS is updated or brought up in a different server the Startup task will again run and regenerate the registry changes (the file is only used to communicate with the role). Or that is my understanding of how startup tasks work - they will be run whenever the OS is brought up.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: The dummy file is basically the endorsed solution (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj129544.aspx) or [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh290696(v=sql.110).aspx) for example).  If the instance is simply rebooted, then the registry values (or whatever changes) will persist.  If the changes are gone, that would mean the whole OS would have been reset, and the dummy file would no longer exist.  I can't think of a circumstance where this doesn't work correctly.

Comment: @mellamokb - you're right. But in early 2011 (4.5 years ago) that technique was not as reliable. Plus VM Role still existed. And my "answer" here fit within current SO guidelines. As I re-read it now, it is, at best, out-of-date. And probably deserving of being punted.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: lol I just looked at your profile, didn't realize you were an Azure Cloud Architect.  Sorry!  I had just stumbled on this question when researching something related and decided to set the record straight :)